# How would I get the number of files selected in a multi file input with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the number of files selected and change a div based on the number. The code I have is this:

HTML:

`<input type="file" name="submit_image[]" id="submit_image" class="fileStyle" multiple>`

Javascript:

```
//Get Files
var files = document.getElementById("submit_image");
function listFiles() {
    var numFiles = files.length;
    alert(numFiles);
}

//Test button to give me number of files
document.getElementById("test").onclick = function (e) {
    listFiles();
}
```

When I click the button it just returns `undefined`. I would be open to doing this in jQuery but I prefer a Vanilla JS method. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed by this code:

```
var list = document.getElementById("submit_image");
function listFiles () {
    var numFiles = list.files.length;
    alert(numFiles);
}

document.getElementById("test").onclick = function (e) {
    listFiles();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to access the `files` property of the input element:

```
var files = document.getElementById("submit_image").files;
```

Comment: Now it's just returning 0.

Comment: @Joe Scotto I tested it and it works fine (on Firefox)

Comment: Is there a way for chrome? I can't just have this working on Firefox.

Comment: dont' have chrome. You can try to move the line `var files = ...` **into** the function `listFiles`.

Comment: @JoeScotto First I point your error and help you to fix it on Chrome, then you use this information to post an own answer. If I would have known how much you appreciate my help I would not have spent time on this.

Comment: the code you posted didn't fix it on chrome, only Firefox. My code worked albeit, it's pretty much the same as what you said.

Comment: @JoeScotto your question was about why you get a `undefined` and not how to make it work on Chrome.

Comment: I thought in web design it's assumed that it should work in multiple browsers, not just one. I'm not going to argue with you like a child, the code I found worked in multiple browsers and answered my question, yours didn't. Have a nice day.